# How to troubleshoot random laptop poweroffs?

Tags: laptop, power, shutdown, thinkpad

My Thinkpad x230 shuts off randomly. There's no shutdown sequence or any delay, just click, off. It can run for hours or days just fine, or do it several times in one day. It boots back up immediately with no delay and works perfectly well otherwise.

I've tried to replicate the behavior by stress testing the cpu to get the system hot and by jostling it around while it's running to see if maybe there's a bad connection somewhere on the motherboard or something.

I've also run the BIOS hardware checker, memtest, fdisk. I've swapped the battery and the charging cable and power supply. Temps are normal, 50c idle, 80 under load. Dmesg has nothing of interest, just normal status messages and then the beginning of the next boot sequence.

I'm at a loss about how to troubleshoot an issue like this.

```
Thinkpad x230
i5-3320M
Arch Linux x64
```

Answer (score 0):

First, that is not a new machine (I have one in the basement)

Do the following:

**(1)** Run the Lenovo System Updater and update all drivers including BIOS.

**(2)** Run the Lenovo Hardware Diagnostics App and look for hardware issues.  A bad or intermittent memory module can cause this. Look for all hardware errors.

**(3)** Run Kaspersky TDSS Killer and look for Root Kit viruses. Root Kit viruses might cause this issue as well.

You should be able to run all these from a bootable USB

TDSS Killer can run as a portable install that you can use.

https://portableapps.com/apps/security/kaspersky-tdsskiller-portable

Comment: Memory stress testing is not a bad thought. On the flup side - Kaspersky TDSS on a Linux box?

Comment: https://portableapps.com/apps/security/kaspersky-tdsskiller-portable   ... TDSS Killer runs as a portable install that you can use.